# Empty list index error

Tags: python, list

I wrote the following two functions:

```
def place_walls(level):
    wall_cords = level[2].split("\n")
    for cord in wall_cords:
        process_coordinate(cord)        

def process_coordinate(coordinate):
    cords = coordinate.split()
    print cords[0]
```

Python returns a list index out of range error. If I print the `cords` variable without an index it prints all the cords in a list, however the last list is an empty list. Might that be the problem, how could that be solved?

The input `level` looks like this:

```
1 0
0 0=r=3 3
4 3
5 3
6 3
7 3
8 3
9 3
10 3
11 3
3 4
```

Comment: `for cord in wall_cords if not None`?

Comment: Be careful, a list doesn't have a split method. Only strings. Could you provide an exemple of what `level` is?

Comment: @fredtantini: OP is not splitting the list, but rather using split to *make* the list

Comment: @ScottHunter `coordinate` is from a splitting (`level[2].split("\n")`) so I thought it was worth noticing

Comment: @fredtantini: No, its from an *element* of a splitting (see the `for` loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is just the last, empty list you have a problem with: clearly, there is no 1st element to print in that case, so wrap it in an `if` statement (for example `if len(cords)>0:`; if the list *is* empty, do whatever is more appropriate for that circumstance.

Comment: Or even `if cords:`; empty sequences evaluate False-y. @VishnuUpadhyay *"your mileage may vary"*.